# How to hide a label using auto layout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a UILabel in a custom button.

to the left of the label I have a UIPageControl. The PageControl might have more or less pages. Now I would like to use auto layout to hide the label when there is not enough room for all three of them. When just changing the width of the label the text gets truncated or clipped. Is there some trick?

[image: UIPageControl UILabel UIButton]

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561269/autolayout-with-hidden-uiviews/19586924#19586924

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in setting the `width` or `height` layout constraint (**don't** set the `frame` directly), so other subviews are laid out properly - but in addition you, you should set its `hidden` property to `YES`

And don't remove subviews - as any other constraints that depend on them will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could override layoutSubViews on your view and programatically remove the label when there is not enough room. I don't think auto layout will do it.

Comment: This will break constraints that depend on the removed label