# Hiding a view above UITableView causes the header of the tableview to be stretched

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, header

I have a UIView with a UITableView right below it. The tableview has a custom header which hold a UISearchbar and a UISegmententedController. The top view and tableview are constrained to each other and to the superview. If I hide the top view, the header of the tableview gets stretched.

Top view visible:

[image: Top view is green and directly under it is the tableView]

Top view hidden (height constraint set to 0):

[image]

My expectation would be that when I hide the top view my tableview content should scroll up, but instead of repositioning the cells, the tableview stretches out the header view.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but if the custom tableView header is created from a xib then it gets messed up. But if the view is created programmatically it works. I don't know why but to fix the problem just needed to create the tableview header programmatically

Bad:

```
if let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? HeaderView { 
  tableview.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Good:

```
tableview.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 80))
```

Comment: Apparently the problem had to do with the autoresizing mask. Not letting the view autoresize for the height seems too have fixed it as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the tableView scroll up, I would recommend getting the height constraint of the top view and reducing it to 0. You can update the height constraint in a `UIView.animate` block to have a smoother transition when showing and hiding the top view.

Refer here for more details: [AutoLayout with hidden UIViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561269/autolayout-with-hidden-uiviews)